# Is there anyway to output a "backspace" character in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there anyway to output a "backspace" character in XSLT?

Like right now the current output is `abc` and i would like to output a *backspace* character such that the output reduces by 1 and becomes `ab`.

Ok I know it probably goes against good coding practice. But i just need it as a quick and dirty hack to solve some issue. I am aware that i could achieve that effect by changing the structure of the program such that the last character `c` never gets output at all (so we do not have to *backspace* it) but there, I need it right now, the fast and dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do, you'll get `abc&#127;`, not `ab`.

Do `<xsl:value-of select="substring($text, 1, string-length($text)-1)" />` where `$text` is `abc` in your case; substitute it for whatever holds the text.

Comment: uh since the output is coming out from other functions i couldn't actually directly apply a substring, but anyway thx for the answer

Comment: Sure you can; just assign the output of the other function to a variable, called `$text` for example, and then do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't emit a backspace character - it's probably worth taking a look at the `substring()` and `string-length()` functions instead